# Interdependent properties in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, properties, dependencies, vue.js

I've got a case of interdependent properties in Vue.js and I'd like to know if there is a cleverer way to set this up. It's a form to define a time span by setting start time (A) and/or finish time (B) and/or a duration (Diff) – here simplified with integers. Depending on which property changes the other ones will be calculated accordingly. If I didn't forget something the rules are as follows:

- A changes B if Diff is set
- A changes B and Diff if B is set and A had previous value
- A changes Diff if B is set and A didn't have previous value
- B changes Diff if A is set
- B changes Diff if A is not set but Diff and B had previous value
- B sets A if A is not set but Diff and B didn't have previous value
- Diff changes B if A is set
- Diff sets A if A is not set but B
- Diff can be the only filled out field

The idea is: Move the span by changing A, expand/contract the span by changing B or Diff. Calculate missing values according to logic.

I've got a working script using `$watch`: https://jsbin.com/korole/edit?html,js,output

Again, is there a cleverer way to set this up? Thanks a lot for any help!

```
var vm = new Vue({

    el: '#calculate-difference',

    data: {
        a: '',
        b: '',
        diff: ''
    },

    methods: {
        updateProperty: function(prop, val) {
            if (parseInt(this[prop]) !== val) this[prop] = val;
        }
    },

    watch: {

        'a': function(val, old) {
            var newB, newDiff;

            if (val === '') return;

            // A changes B if Diff is set
            if (this.diff !== '') {
                newB = parseInt(val) + parseInt(this.diff);
                this.updateProperty('b', newB);
            }

            // A changes B and Diff if B is set and A had previous value
            else if (old !== '' && this.b !== '') {
                newB = parseInt(this.b) + (parseInt(val) - parseInt(old));
                this.updateProperty('b', newB);
                newDiff = parseInt(this.b) - parseInt(val);
                this.updateProperty('diff', newDiff);
            }

            // A changes Diff if B is set and A didn't have previous value
            else if (this.b !== '') {
                newDiff = parseInt(this.b) - parseInt(val);
                this.updateProperty('diff', newDiff);
            }
        },

        'b': function(val, old) {
            var newDiff;

            if (val === '') return;

            // B changes Diff if A is set
            if (this.a !== '') {
                newDiff = parseInt(val) - parseInt(this.a);
                this.updateProperty('diff', newDiff);
            }

            // B changes Diff if A is not set but Diff and B had previous value
            else if (old !== '' && this.diff !== '') {
                newDiff = parseInt(this.diff) + (parseInt(val) - parseInt(old));
                this.updateProperty('diff', newDiff);
            }

            // B sets A if A is not set but Diff and B didn't have previous value
            else if (this.diff !== '') {
                newA = parseInt(val) - parseInt(this.diff);
                this.updateProperty('a', newA);
            }
        },

        'diff': function(val) {
            var newB, newA;

            if (val === '') return;

            // Diff changes B if A is set
            if (this.a !== '') {
                newB = parseInt(this.a) + parseInt(val);
                this.updateProperty('b', newB);
            }

            // Diff sets A if A is not set but B
            else if (this.b !== '') {
                newA = parseInt(this.b) - parseInt(val);
                this.updateProperty('a', newA);
            }
        }

    }

});
```

### Edit: Yes, there is a cleverer way.

Thank you, Jeff! Avoid `$watch`, use [Computed Properties](http://vuejs.org/guide/computed.html). The code is cleaner and easier to grasp. A changes B and B changes A. The Difference gets calculated.

The improved script using computed properties: https://jsbin.com/jixili/edit?html,js,output

```
var vm = new Vue({

    el: '#calculate-difference',

    data: {
        store: {
            a: '',
            b: '',
            diff: ''
        }
    },

    computed: {
        a: {
            get: function() {
                return this.store.a;
            },
            set: function(val) {
                var old = this.store.a;
                this.store.a = val;

                if (this.diff === '') return;

                if (val === '' && this.b !== '') {
                    this.b = '';
                }

                if (val !== '' && this.b === '') {
                    this.b = parseInt(val) + parseInt(this.diff);
                }

                if (val !== '' && this.b !== '' && old !== '') {
                    this.b = parseInt(this.a) + (parseInt(this.b) - parseInt(old));
                }
            }
        },
        b: {
            get: function() {
                return this.store.b;
            },
            set: function(val) {
                this.store.b = val;

                if (this.diff === '') return;

                if (val === '' && this.a !== '') {
                    this.a = '';
                }

                if (val !== '' && this.a === '') {
                    this.a = parseInt(val) - parseInt(this.diff);
                }
            }
        },
        diff: {
            get: function() {
                if (this.a !== '' && this.b !== '') {
                    this.store.diff = parseInt(this.b) - parseInt(this.a);
                }

                return this.store.diff;
            },
            set: function(val) {
                this.store.diff = val;

                if (val === '') return;

                if (this.a !== '') {
                    this.b = parseInt(this.a) + parseInt(val);
                }

                if (this.a === '' && this.b !== '') {
                    this.a = parseInt(this.b) - parseInt(val);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `diff` a computed property and use a getter and setter function so you will be able to update diff as well.  Check out http://vuejs.org/guide/computed.html#Computed_Setter.  This works with `v-model`, so it will automatically show the value of diff, and call `set` when you change it.

Edited based on your comment, you could make a property to hold the value of `diff` and then only set A or B if you want to based on your app logic

```
var vm = new Vue({

  el: '#calculate-difference',

  data: {
    a: '',
    b: '',
    diffValue:''
  },
  computed:{
    diff:{
      get:function() {
        return parseInt(this.b) - parseInt(this.a);
      },
      set:function(newDiff){
        //Store the value of the diff input
        diffValue = newDiff;

        //Update A and B based on new difference, only if needed
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I guess I didn't clarify well, that even just a duration will do in the form, so I can't (always) compute the value. It a form to track an activity and I don't want to force the user to provide specific start and finish times. Maybe what I have is already how it's done in that case?

Comment: @M165437 Would this edit help?  I think making `diff` a computed property makes the most sense for your app.  Being that it is the difference between two static values it just makes sense.  You may have to do some type of workaround like the edit above to make it fit, but this will be much less code if you can get it working.